# How to CMake compile a library as part of my app's source and not as static/shared library?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, cmake, clion

I'd like to be able to debug my app at the same time as the library(ies) with **VSCode** and **CLion** using **CMake**.

```
.
+-- lib
|   +-- CMakeLists.txt
|   +-- lib.c
|   +-- lib.h
+-- app
|   +-- CMakeLists.txt
|   +-- app.c
|   +-- app.h
```

As an example, let's say I want to compile my app with the [{fmt}](https://fmt.dev/latest/usage.html) library as part of the source of my app, to see the flow inside the fmt lib's codebase when I debug my code.

Obviously, I don't want to copy all the commands of the cmake file of the lib into my cmake file of my app, a way to link the CMakeLists.txt of the lib to my lib's one would be the best.

In the end, my app uses the static/shared library but there are already SO questions about that and some examples in the open-source world.

FYI, my app's source files use `#include <lib.h>`.

#### Edit:

I just wanted to clarify a point, using {fmt} as source is much easier since it can be used as a *header-file-only library*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that cmake's `add_subdirectory` (https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_subdirectory.html) does exactly what you need.

It will include library's `CMakeLists.txt` to your project and you will be free to use its targets in functions like `target_link_libraries`.

Simple example: Let's assume that you checked out the fmt source code to fmt folder.

```
.
+-- fmt (fmt source code)
+-- CMakeLists.txt
+-- main.cpp
```

CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0)
project(example)

add_subdirectory(fmt)

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC fmt)
```

main.cpp:

```
#include "fmt/core.h"
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout << fmt::format("The answer is {}.", 42) << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Wow, thanks, I didn't expect it to be that much easy. I'll try! I'm quite confused with CMake as a beginner, it isn't straightforward and takes time to really understand CMakeLists.txt files of other projects.

Answer (score 1):

If you compile the library with debug information into either a static or a shared library you link against and not move the sources, I see no reason why you wouldn't be able to debug it as part as your larger app.

If you really want to compile "as part of the source" you may produce the object files and include them in your main build - you can use

```
add_library(dummy OBJECT <source files>)
```

to produce the object files. However I see no reason why you would like to do this.

Overall, looks like @luantkow's answer is the right way to do what you need.

Comment: Not necessary with debug info, rather I'd like to be able to set breakpoints in the IDE. I believe the IDE needs the source files rather than the object files. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: I think that the debug info includes precisely the information necessary to set/hit breakpoints, so you need to make sure you compile with it enabled (-g for gcc, /Z[i,I,7] for microsoft compiler).

Comment: I'm a moron, of course, I believe that's automatically set by the IDE with `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE="Debug"`.

Comment: It is, which is certainly convenient